# Форма не отправляет данные на сервере

Tags: php, post, form

Форма отправляет просто пустой массив и происходит это только на сервере. Проверял на локалке, всё прекрасно работает

```html
<form action="send.php" method="POST">
  <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Название">
  <input name="category" type="text" placeholder="Категория">
  <textarea name="dosage" placeholder="Дозировка"></textarea>
  <textarea name="indications" placeholder="Показания"></textarea>
  <textarea name="contraindications" placeholder="Противопоказания"></textarea>
  <textarea name="pharmacodynamics" placeholder="Фармакодинамика"></textarea>
  <textarea name="side_effects" placeholder="Побочные эффекты"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
</form>
```

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$dosage = $_POST['dosage'];
$indications = $_POST['indications'];
$contraindications = $_POST['contraindications'];
$pharmacodynamics = $_POST['pharmacodynamics'];
$side_effects = $_POST['side_effects'];

var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

На сервере `var_dump()` выводит просто `array(0) { }`

На локалке выводит всю форму `array(7) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["category"]=> string(0) "" ["dosage"]=> string(0) "" ["indications"]=> string(0) "" ["contraindications"]=> string(0) "" ["pharmacodynamics"]=> string(0) "" ["side_effects"]=> string(0) "" }`

Answer (score 1):

В общем, нашёл решение.

Переместил файл с обработчиком в корневую папку и всё заработало `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`